# cgroups, cpuset changing the cpuset of some processes fail

Tags: linux, cgroups

I am trying to "reserve" a core on a CPU for performance measurement. I have mounted a cpuset cgroups vfs. I created two subgroups like this:

```
/cpuset.cpu_exclusive    1
/cpuset.cpus             0-3
/cpuset.mems             0

# Everything on the PC except what I want to measure
/All/cpuset.cpu_exclusive    1
/All/cpuset.cpus             1-3
/All/cpuset.mems             0

# The measurement processes only (i.e. the shell + a binary to test)
/Timing/cpuset.cpu_exclusive    1
/Timing/cpuset.cpus             0
/Timing/cpuset.mems             0
```

I am able to move many processes to the "All" group, but I fail to do so for some (those who look like kernel processes). For instance, ksoftirqd has a pid of 3:

```
[root@Io:/vfsroot]# echo 3 > All/tasks 
echo: write error: invalid argument
```

Moreover, for some process I can see them in All/tasks but they'll still be running on the wrong cpu (here cpu #0, with a shell).

```
[root@Io:/vfsroot]# echo 28362 > All/tasks 
[root@Io:/vfsroot]# ps -eo pid,psr | grep "0$"
...
28362   0
```

For those I am wondering whether that's because they have not woken up since I changed their cpuset and ps displays the last cpu they ran on...

I can change my current shell cpu quite effectively. (Make it appear and disappear from /Timing/tasks and see it change CPU with ps)

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu and installed cgroups using apt-get if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cset-shield` manpage has this note:

> If the optional --kthread=on option is given to the shield command, then all kernel threads (with exception of the per-CPU bound interrupt kernel threads) are also moved to the system set.

I interpret this as "(some) interrupt kernel threads are CPU-bound". From its name, `ksoftirqd` (kernel soft IRQ daemon) seems a likely candidate! (As a sidenote, I don't think these kernel threads will affect performance measurements.)

Comment: Haven't retried this in a while but that sounds like a good possibility, thanks.